# Knockout doesn't observable style property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

all! I have the following HTML:

```
  <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Simple app</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: tests">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: testName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: result"></td>
                <td><button data-bind="click: runTest, style: {backgroundColor: color}">Run test</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and the following js:

```
function Test(testName, test) {
    var vm = {};

    vm.result = ko.observable(false);
    vm.testName = testName;
    vm.color = ko.computed(function (){
        return vm.result === true ? 'green' : 'red';
    }, vm);

    vm.test = test;
    vm.runTest = function () {
        var result = vm.test();
        vm.result(result);
    }

    return vm;
}

function TestsViewModel(modelName, tests) {
    var vm = {};

    vm.modelName = modelName;
    vm.tests = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++){
        vm.tests.push(Test(tests[i].title, tests[i].test));
    }

    return vm;
}

function test1() {
    return true;
}

function test2(){
    return false;
}

function test3(){
    return void (0) === undefined;
}

ko.applyBindings(TestsViewModel('Name', [{
    title: 'Test1',
    test: test1
}, {
    title: 'Test2',
    test: test2
}, {
    title: 'Test3',
    test: test3
}]));
```

I want to change color of button depending on the value of result property. But knockout doesn't check the value when result was changed. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the parenthesis:

```
vm.color = ko.computed(function (){
    return vm.result() === true ? 'green' : 'red'; // vm.result()
}, vm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your computed "color" you have to use the result as an observable not just as a property. vm.result**()** not vm.result.

```
vm.color = ko.computed(function (){
        return vm.result() === true ? 'green' : 'red';
    }, vm);
```